# Returns the value of the array when the condition was true on the n -th most recent occurrence

Tags: arrays, numpy, pandas

I have defined a function

```
result = valuewhen(condition, array)
```

which returns the value of the `array` when the `condition` was `True` on the most recent occurrence:

```
import pandas as pd
pd1 = pd.Series([0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1])
pd2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])

def valuewhen(a1, a2):
    res = pd.Series(index=a1.index) 
    res.loc[a1 == 1] = a2
    res = res.ffill().fillna(0)
    return res

result = valuewhen(pd1, pd2)
```

Example:

```
result = valuewhen(array1, array2)

array1  array2  result
     0       1       0
     0       2       0
     1       3       3
     1       4       4
     0       5       4
     0       6       4
     1       7       7
     0       8       7
     1       9       9
     0      10       9
     0      11       9
     0      12       9
     1      13      13
```

Now I want to return the value of the `array` when the `condition` was `True` on the `n`th most recent occurrence:

```
result = ValueWhen(condition, array[, n]) #[if missing n=1]
```

Example:

```
Result = ValueWhen(array1, array2, 1)
Result2 = ValueWhen(array1, array2, 2)

array1  array2  Result  Result2
     0       1       0        0
     0       2       0        0
     1       3       3        0
     1       4       4        3
     0       5       4        3
     0       6       4        3
     1       7       7        4
     0       8       7        4
     1       9       9        7
     0      10       9        7
     0      11       9        7
     0      12       9        7
     1      13      13        9
```

What is the most Pythonic way to add parameter `n` to this function?

Comment: Well, this wouldn't occur to me before seeing Result and Result2 side by side, but the pattern seems to be consistent.  So really you just need to get all the values and patterns from ```valuewhen()```, and then (in this example) map ```3->0```,```4->3```, ```7->4```, etc. and just do that ```n``` times.  That's a little tedious, but straightforward.  I could be wrong but I think generalizing the function itself would be really hard.

Comment: As an additional suggestion, you might look at ```unique()``` and ```shift()``` to help in mapping the values.